# How can I graph horizontal error bars in java?

Tags: java, graphics, graph

I am working on a project, in which I must graph both horizontal and vertical error bars. Most libraries I have found graph only vertical bars. Is there any way you know to graph horizontal error bars?

Comment: jfreechart has http://javaarm.com/file/opensource/jfreechart/1.0.14/jfreechart-1.0.14-demo_study/XYErrorRendererDemo2.png and http://javaarm.com/file/opensource/jfreechart/1.0.14/jfreechart-1.0.14-demo_study/XYErrorRendererDemo1.png but maybe not the horizontal way you're looking for. Anyway, this may be a question better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you received any sample? I am having a similar requirement

Comment: No, I ended up not implementing the horizontal error bars.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the jfreechartlibrary. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

it has that functionality

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartHorizontalBarChartDemo2.htm

Comment: like this http://javaarm.com/file/opensource/jfreechart/1.0.14/jfreechart-1.0.14-demo_study/XYErrorRendererDemo2.png

Comment: Exactly, I am looking to graph a line graph which includes both vertical and horizontal error bars. But thanks.